# Classification criteria equation of decision trees

Tags: scikit-learn, cart

Can someone explain what does the term *I(y=k)* stand for in the equation for p_mk ?

[image]

Comment: You can tell from the description that $I(y=k)$ must be used to count the class-$k$ observations in $Q_m.$ What do you suppose would work for that purpose?  For more information, search [Indicator function](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Indicator+function%22).

Comment: Thanks for your answer !

Answer (score 1):

Here, $I$ represents an indicator function, which takes a value of 1 when the input is equal to some value, and 0 otherwise. Here, $I(y=k)$ returns 1 when $y$ is equal to $k$, and 0 otherwise. The this formula just counts up the number of instances where the class value is equal to $k$, and divides by the total number of instances to get a proportion.